# How do you use python-decouple to load a .env file outside the expected paths?

Tags: python, django, config, decoupling, python-decouple

I'm forced to keep my `.env` file in a non-standard path outside the root of my project (in a separate directory altogether).

Let's say I have my Django project in `/var/projects/my_project`, though I have my `.env` file in `/opt/envs/my-project/.env` where my `SECRET_KEY` is stored. In my `settings.py` file, I'd like to explicitly use the `.env` file at that path so that I can still do this:

```
from decouple import config
secret_key = config('SECRET_KEY')
```

Comment: Keeping the .env file outside the project root folder is a good methodology in terms of security wise!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I figured it out.

Instead of importing `decouple.config` and doing the usual `config('FOOBAR')`, create a new `decouple.Config` object using `RepositoryEnv('/path/to/env-file')`.

```
from decouple import Config, RepositoryEnv

DOTENV_FILE = '/opt/envs/my-project/.env'
env_config = Config(RepositoryEnv(DOTENV_FILE))

# use the Config().get() method as you normally would since 
# decouple.config uses that internally. 
# i.e. config('SECRET_KEY') = env_config.get('SECRET_KEY')
SECRET_KEY = env_config.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: Which version did you use? django-decouple version 2.1 doesn't seem to have Config or RepositoryEnv.

Comment: @BarneySzabolcs I'm using 3.8 version

Answer (score 24):

If you look at the decouple implementation, config is just a pre-instantiated AutoConfig:

```
config = AutoConfig()
```

But AutoConfig takes as optional argument `search_path` so we can do the following:

```
from decouple import AutoConfig
config = AutoConfig(search_path='/opt/envs/my-project')
```

Then you can do as usual:

```
secret_key = config('SECRET_KEY')
```

Comment: I was testing with a different folder within the root of the git repo and had to do this.

Comment: Which version did you use? django-decouple version 2.1 doesn't seem to support arguments for AutoConfig's constructor.

Comment: I use 3.6 version and it works well

Answer (score 2):

Now, `django-decouple==2.1` supports having `settings.ini` and `.env` files in any parent directory of the project dir.

(And the old methods don't work anymore. - from decouple import Config, RepositoryEnv does not work, AutoConfig does not have search_path as parameter.)

This is convenient because you would want to keep the `settings.ini` in the project folder on your local machine and you would want to have clean checkouts on the staging/prod server, thus the `settings.ini` is better located outside the project folder.

### UPDATE:

I would still explicitly define the location of the settings file.
(I'm currently using python-decouple==3.8)

```
from decouple import Config, RepositoryEnv
from os.path import join
from mysite import BASE_DIR
config = Config(RepositoryEnv(join(BASE_DIR, 'settings.ini')))

DEBUG = config('DEBUG', cast=bool)
secret_key = config('SECRET_KEY')
```