# Celery and .env file with django-decouple

Tags: django, django-celery

I am starting my celery in a separate terminal with command

```
-A app worker -E --concurrency=5 -l debug -P eventlet
```

but it can't find .env file. I have this this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570838/how-do-you-use-python-decouple-to-load-a-env-file-outside-the-expected-paths) which appears similar to mine but still gives me errors. The error I am getting is

decouple.UndefinedValueError()

My directory structure is:

```
  env/
    scripts/
    app/
       app/
          celery.py
          settings.py
          urls.py
    manage.py
    .env
```

Comment: Well, you have to create .env file and put the variables in there.

Comment: Where is your celery app file , django settings file and where is your .env file ? I mean directory structure

Comment: @MohammadUmair let me update my question

Comment: try `celery -A app.app worker -E --concurrency=5 -l debug -P eventlet` from manage.py level